# Same string is stored in all elements of array

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm trying to save different strings into an array of char* but for some reason it saves the same string into every element of the array even though I am storing different strings to the elements.

```
char string[99];
char line[99];
FILE* out = fopen("data.out", "w");
char *words[999];
int wcount = 0;


 while(fscanf(fpointer, "%s", string) != EOF)
{
    if((strlen(string) + strlen(line))-1 <= number)
    {
        strcat(line, string);
        char word[99];
        strcpy(word, string);
        words[wcount] = word;
        printf("should have saved %s at %d\n", word, wcount);
        wcount++;

        if(strlen(line) < number)
        {
            strcat(line, " ");
        }
        puts(line);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(out,"%s", line);
        fprintf(out, "\n");
        strcpy(line, string);
        strcat(line, " ");
    }
}

fprintf(out, "%s", line);

printf("wcount is %d\n", wcount);
puts(words[0]);
puts(words[1]);
puts(words[2]);
```

The print statement that starts with "should have saved" prints the correct string that should be saved into the words array but the print statements at the end show that the last word stored is in every element of the array.

Comment: In this statement words[wcount] = word; all elements of the array words contain the same address of the (first character of the) local variable word. So the code does not make sense and moreover has undefined behavior.

Comment: What version of C are you compiling with?

Comment: All the pointers point to the same `word`, so the are *not* different. (And the `word` isn't even there anymore when you try to print it at the end). You would have to copy the words to some storage, not just set pointers to it.

Comment: Several thousand dupes:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this?
Can't test it right now.

```
 char **words = NULL;
 while(fscanf(fpointer, "%s", string) != EOF)
{
    if((strlen(string) + strlen(line))-1 <= number)
    {
        strcat(line, string);
        words = realloc(words,sizeof(char *)*(wcount+1));
        words[wcount] = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(string)+1));
        strcpy(words[wcount], string);
        printf("should have saved %s at %d\n", words[wcount], wcount);
        wcount++;

        if(strlen(line) < number)
        {
            strcat(line, " ");
        }
        puts(line);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(out,"%s", line);
        fprintf(out, "\n");
        strcpy(line, string);
        strcat(line, " ");
    }
}

fprintf(out, "%s", line);

printf("wcount is %d\n", wcount);
puts(words[0]);
puts(words[1]);
puts(words[2]);
```

Comment: That doesn't work it just says "-bash: ./wordproc.c: Permission denied". But originally I had char *words[999]; rather than char **words = NULL; and I forgot to put it on my question originally.

Comment: c files aren't executable did you mean to run ./a.out (assuming you have compiled it)? You probably want to use my solution which dynamically allocates the array so that you can store an infinite amount of words.